# AngularJS - Dynamically change currency symbol on a Filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

**Question Background:**

I have a drop-down that contains 4 different country options these being: UK (United Kingdom), US (United States), FR (France), GER (German). Depending on which drop-down value is selected I need to filter a price on my Controllers Scope object to show the correct currency symbol, for example:

If I select 'FR' in the checkbox, I would expect to see the '€' symbol on the filter:

[image]

If I would to select 'UK' i would expect to see the '£' appended and so on.

**The Issue:**

As stated above I have 4 different countries I can select and therefore I need to be able to ***dynamcially*** change the currency filter.

I have attempted to set this by a model property on the Scope but It hasn't worked so far.

**The Code:**

Currently I am using the standard AngularJS `Currency` filter, as shown:

```
       {{maxTextVal | currency : "&euro;" : 2}}
```

`maxTextVal` is the value on the controllers Scope object. In the code above I have hard-coded the euro code (€) to produce the symbol, **it is this filter value that I need to dynamically set.**

Is it possible to change this value at run-time? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you might also want to consider https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n that will automatically select the right currency based on the region of your browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to change this at run-time but I'm not sure if there is an option at the currency filter directly.

Any way, you can write a custom filter that's using `$sce.trustAsHtml(value)` to correctly display the symbol. Or you could also inject the filter with `currencyFilter` to your scope and call that function and use `$sce` there.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/vkr1f2wg/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .filter('currencyWithLocale', function(currencyFilter, $sce) {
     return function(input, locale) {
         locale = locale || {currency: '$'};
         return $sce.trustAsHtml(currencyFilter(input, locale.currency));
        }
    })
 .controller('mainCtrl', MainCtrl);
    
function MainCtrl($sce) {
 var vm = this;
    angular.extend(vm, {
     total: 10.1,
        locales: [{
         id:0,
            short: 'GER',
            currency: '&euro;'
        }, {
         id:1,
            short: 'FR',
            currency: '&euro;'
        },{
         id:2,
            short: 'UK',
            currency: '&#163;'
        }]
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
    <select ng-model="ctrl.selectedLocale" ng-options="locale as locale.short for locale in ctrl.locales">
    </select>
    <span ng-bind-html="ctrl.total | currencyWithLocale: ctrl.selectedLocale"></span> 
    <!--<br/>
    below is not working because it's not $sanitized.<br/>
    {{ctrl.total | currency: ctrl.selectedLocale.currency}}-->

</div>
```

Comment: I want like this after on click

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the literal "€", pass a scope variable that contains the currently selected currency:

```
{{maxTextVal | currency : selectedCurrency : 2}}
```

Or, assuming you have a selected country, and that the country contains a currency:

```
{{maxTextVal | currency : selectedCountry.currency : 2}}
```