# AngularJS: Currency filter not displaying symbol using code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters, angular-controller

I am trying to display currency symbol using currency code dynamically.

It's not working. It worked on my older projects. I am not sure what changed in currency filter.

This is my html

```
<h2>{{8.99 | currency:'USD':true}}</h2>
```

It should display $. But it is displaying USD.

I also tried in controller. It is not displaying $.

```
$filter('currency')(100, "USD", true);
```

Can anyone tell me what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is you are using angular syntax not angularjs syntax, just use currency filter

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-app>
        <p> {{ 8.99 | currency }} </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It there any way to get desired result i agularjs? I mean symbol according to code.

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779353/angularjs-dynamically-change-currency-symbol-on-a-filter

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `currency` filter:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body style="font:15px Verdana;">
    <div ng-app>
        <p> {{ 8.99 | currency }} </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Or you can also specify `currency:'$'` for that. Using ``currency:` will allow you to explicitly specify any symbol you want to use for that currency.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body style="font:15px Verdana;">
    <div ng-app>
        <p> {{ 8.99 | currency:'$' }} </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I will have currency code dynamic. I want to display symbol accordingly.